# NSUserDefaults Returns nil when I Return to View Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm have a `UITableViewCell` where I'm saving/overwriting objects into an array each time a cell has been selected and saving into `NSUserDefaults`. The issue is that when I return to the view controller and try to retrieve it, it returns nil?

In `viewDidLoad`

```
    var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()       
    if let data = userDefaults.objectForKey("teams") as? NSData {
        let teamObjects = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data)  as! [Team]
        println(teamObjects)
    }
```

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
   var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
   let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.teamSelected)
    userDefaults.setObject(encodedData, forKey: "teams")
    userDefaults.synchronize()
```

When I move the code from `viewDidLoad` to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` it retrieves the objects from NSUserDefaults with no issues? Why cant it do this from viewDidLoad?

Comment: What is the purpose of the archive/unarchived lines? What is the data structure/persistence you are going for?

Comment: Since i'm using a custom Object class

Comment: What do you mean by "return to viewController"? Do you mean when you restart the app?

Comment: Just if i navigate from another view back to this view. I'm using the SWRevealController, so i will be navigating around

Comment: If you navigate back to this view, viewDidLoad will not be called (if you're seeing it called, then you're not really going back, you're creating a new instance). Do you need this data to persist between launches of your app? If not, you shouldn't be using NSUserDefaults.

Comment: sorry for being in objective-c.  have you implemented the - (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder and - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder in your custom class?

Comment: Yes i have done that :) otherwise i would also get an error trying to add my teamSelected into NSUserDefaults

Comment: I built a similar project real quick and the code works. When you start the app, breakpoint in `viewDidLoad` and ensure that the code works and doesn't return nil. I think that @rdelmar may be onto the issue. Navigating back from another view controller will not call `viewDidLoad` If you want to load data from `NSUserDefaults` when you return from another view controller, then this code needs to be in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`.